# How to get netmask?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, network-programming, netmask

I know how to get from ifconfig. (linux)
But is there another way? Can found it in socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use IO#ioctl. This is totally non-portable. On my linux box this code words:

```
require 'socket'
sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM,0)
buf = ["eth0",""].pack('a16h16')
sock.ioctl(0x891b, buf)
netmask = "#{buf[20]}.#{buf[21]}.#{buf[22]}.#{buf[23]}" #=> "255.255.255.240"
```

Ioctl differs considerably between systems and I had to look through a few system header files to get the right sizes for the [].pack, the location of the address in buf and the numeric value for SIOCGIFBRDADDR (the first argument to ioctl).

If these values don't work for you I can give you more information on how to find them.

Comment: Edited to rename the variable - it really is the netmask, not the broadcast ;)